# asp.net mvc IsAuthenticated attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, attributes

is any solution to mark method like this

```
[IsAuthenticated(true)]
        public ActionResult Profile()
        {

            return View();
        }
```

not call `if (request.IsAuthenticated)` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx):

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Profile()
{
    return View();
}
```